# JQuery Datatables Ajax dynamic columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying draw datatable using ajax in it. if I manually create object array of columns it works, but when create columns from initComplete, there is an error "Cannot read property aDataSort", I think initComplete works after drawing table, because in **cols** array has values after ending datatable initialization. How can I create columns object array after ajax response?

```
var columnArrayManual = [{"data": "column1"},{"data": "column1"}];
var cols = [];
tblClients = $("#tblClients").DataTable(
            {
                "ajax": {
                    "url": "/index.php?controller=controller&act=controllerMethod&ajx=1",
                    "dataSrc": "data",
                    type: 'POST',
                    "data": function (d) {
                        var a = arguments[0];
                        return a;
                    }
                },
                "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
                    $.each(json.data[0], function (i, item) {
                      var col = {"data" : i};
                      cols.push(col);
                    })
                },
                "columns": cols
            }
         )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the sorting at server side for ajax datatables and understand the format in which datatables jquery plugin accepts the returning data i.e.

```
[{
 "columns": [{
  "title": "col1_name",
  "data": "col1_name"
 }, {
  "title": "col2_name",
  "data": "col2_name"
 }],
 "data": [{
  "col1_name": "col1 data",
  "col2_name": "col2 data"
 }, {
  "col1_name": "col1 data",
  "col2_name": "col2 data"
 }]
}]
```

I have created an article with code in ASP.NET MVC platform for this approach, you can look into it for understanding the flow i.e. [Jquery Ajax Datatables with Dynamic Columns](https://www.asmak9.com/2020/03/aspnet-mvc-jquery-ajax-datatables-with.html)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fill data from ajax response in dataSrc, instead of datatable initialization

```
"ajax": {
                    "url": "/index.php?controller=controller&act=controllerMethod&ajx=1",
                    "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
                        // I have created object array here
                        return json.data ;
                    }, 
                    "type": 'POST',
                    "data": function (d) {
                        var a = arguments[0];
                        return a;
                    }
                },
```

and it worked!